# mysql 2 level of multiple entries

Tags: mysql

I am new to mysql and I was not able to find a good explanatory example to the following problem. I have a set of stations and each station may have records for multiple years. Now each year may have a number of different timesteps of  measurements. I got lost on the design of this database.
The most appropriate procedure would be to build:
1) table with stations and different columns for the different years (?)
2) extra tables for each year which will contain somehow the station id and the timesteps?

a small example :

```
cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Stations(     \
            StationsID  INT AUTO_INCREMENT,           \
            Code      VARCHAR(3)       ,              \
            year6     VARCHAR(1)       ,              \
            year7     VARCHAR(1)       ,              \
            PRIMARY KEY pk_Stations (StationsID)      \
            );");
```

tables for the years : (?)

```
cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Times2006(  \
            times2006ID  INT AUTO_INCREMENT,      \
            1hourly      VARCHAR(1)    ,          \
            3hourly      VARCHAR(1)    ,          \
            day          VARCHAR(1)    ,          \
            night        VARCHAR(1)    ,          \
            PRIMARY KEY pk_Times (times2006ID)    \
            );");
```

Then the same for the rest of the years? And I guess I need some extra table then to connect them somehow??
Thank you for your patience and your help.

Comment: why even bother with multiple tables? one table `times`, and a field inside that records the date **AND** time of the measurement. you can trivially pull our records  for any date period using mysql extensive [date/time functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html) e.g. `select * from measurements where year(timestamp) = 2015`

Comment: Thank you for your response. I think I made a mistake here. By saying timesteps I meant different types of measurements.. so each year may contain 1hourly or 3hourly etc... So I would like to get for which year a station has a measurement and what type..

Comment: then a timestamp/typeof_measurement field will do as well. anytime you're creating tables based on contents of the data, that content can be put into a field in a single table.

Comment: So if I understood it right, a table should be with the stations and the years and then another one with the station id and the type of measurement? I should say that might this type change from year to year. I think I can not put it as one single field. Thank you for your patience.. :)